# For path $\gamma(t)$ there exists $\vec{p}$ with $\gamma(t)=\vec{p}$ $\forall$ $t\in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$-function, let 
$I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$
be open, and let $\gamma: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$-path
that follows the gradient of $f$ [i.e., $\gamma'(t)=(\nabla f)(\gamma(t))$ $\forall$ $t\in I$]. Suppose that $a<b$ are two 
numbers in the interval $I$ such that $\gamma (a) = \gamma (b)$.
I want to prove that $\exists \vec{p} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
$\gamma (t) = \vec{p}$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.

My approach:

> Since $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$, $\gamma'(a)=(\nabla f)(\gamma(a))=(\nabla f)(\gamma(b))=\gamma'(b)$. By the MVT, $\exists c\in [a,b]$ such that $0=\|\gamma(a)-\gamma(b)\|=\|\gamma'(c)\||a-b|$, so that $\|\gamma'(c)\|=0$, hence $\gamma'(c)=\vec{0}=(\nabla f)(\gamma(c))$. Now I think the next step is to prove that $\gamma'(a)=0=\gamma'(b)$. But I don't see how.

Intuitively I understand that if the tangent vectors to $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$ are the same, then $\gamma$ must be constant on the entire interval, but I don't quite yet see how to prove this fact mathematically. Would appreciate some insight from you.

Comment: Your reasoning would apply to any smooth closed curve with nonzero tangent vector (for such a curve you'd also have equal tangents after one period). So your proof implies such curves don't exist, which is not true.

Comment: (hint: you are ignoring the fact that the tangent can be orthogonal to the position vector. The norm equality you've written down is only an inequality)

Comment: @Thomas For a smooth closed curve, wouldn't it be true that the tangents at $a$ and $b$ would be orthogonal when $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$? In the sense that they would have slopes with different signs.

Comment: @Thomas So it appears that, since the gradient of $\gamma(a)$ is orthogonal to $\gamma(a)$, $\langle (\nabla f)(\gamma(a)), \gamma(a) \rangle=0$. But this implies that either the gradient is $0$ (stationary point) or $\gamma(a)=0$. I'm not sure how this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$  be defined by $g(t)=f( \gamma(t))$. Then

$g'(t) =(\nabla f)(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)=\gamma'(t)*\gamma'(t)=||\gamma'(t)||^2 \ge 0$.

Hence $g$ is increasing. From $g(a)=f( \gamma(a))=f( \gamma(b))=g(b)$ we then deduce that $g$ is constant . Therefore

$||\gamma'(t)||^2=g'(t)=0$. Thus

$\gamma'(t)=0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.